# How can I get CSS media properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I can make `@media` queries in Javascript (e.g., check if a webpage matches `@media (max-width: 640px)`).  However, I cannot seem to find any way to find the actual `@media` properties themselves. For example, the `monochrome` value, or the `aspect-ratio`, or `color-index`.

I could brute-force it, with a giant set of MediaQueryList queries, but that seems like a bad approach.

Am I missing something obvious? I haven't been able to find any way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the CSS rules at the `styleSheet` array.

```
var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = styleSheet.cssRules || styleSheet.rules;
```

Comment: Somewhat weirdly, *styleSheets* is not included on MDN as property of [*document*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). However, `document.styleSheets` is given in an example for a [*StyleSheetList* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList). Also worth noting that `styleSheet.cssRules || styleSheet.rules` is necessary for cross browser support and *cssRules* is the standardised way. :-)

Comment: Ah, but those are the **rules** - I'm not interested in the rules, I want the _properties_.